# State-sanctioned historical "truth"

Tags: historiography

My question on [Authenticity of the Russian birch bark manuscripts](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/17286/authenticity-of-the-russian-birch-bark-manuscripts) prompted me to think about the problem that one of the commentators called "state sanctioned *truth*"*

These are historical events, characters, old books or anything the official history has built upon, and which are wrong, fake, never existed, never happened, happened in another country and another time - you get my point. But these things are so important for current political régime, national pride, sense of unity etc that they are still alive in history textbooks and conventional wisdom of the country.

Do such things exist/existed? If yes, what are the examples of such "deceptions"?

*The manuscripts we spoke about not necessarily belong to this category

Comment: Er ... every culture, country, religion, family, ... has these. I think this is f-a-a-a-r too broad! Not only that, it is really asking for a list.

Comment: @andy256  There are questions on History SE asking for "examples". So in this sense, it looks acceptable. It's quite broad, you're right. I wasn't sure when posting and chose to let the community decide.

Comment: Examples of this is pretty much a dime a dozen, so this is definitely too broad.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invented_tradition

Comment: Examples are abundant.  But your previous question about Russian birch manuscripts is really interesting. Were you able to find any relevant information?

Comment: @twosheds Very interesting, thanks! Although the question was put on hold by the community, it was still worth asking :)

Comment: @Alex I think I've read pretty much everything available on them in Russian, excluding scientific papers. It seems that they're not *entirely* fake due to the fact that there're thousands people involved in process of excavation, many of them volunteering students. So if if we believe they are fakes, we have to believe that there is a global conspiracy around them, which is unlikely to be true.

However, there are quite a lot of strange facts in this story. <continued>

Comment: @Alex <continued> First is the fact that they were preserved for such a long period of time without any special conservation (manuscripts from Iudaea and Egypt survived because they were *intentionally* conserved). It's still very counterintuitive. Second, they were never tested by independent laboratory and their authenticity is mainly based on the authority of two main researches, Valentin Yanin https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valentin_Yanin and Andrey Zalizniak http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrey_Zaliznyak, both *academians* and very important people in Soviet/Russian science. <continued>

Comment: @Alex  <continued> However, they have little or none scientific authority outside or USSR/Russia, which is strange considering the importance of their research. It also gives us the reason not to trust them entirely.

Comment: @Timofey: I also read Yanin and Zalizniak, and It is very strange that I could never find an expert outside of Russia/SU who would comment on this. There is a substantial Western literature about other "state-approved" finds of Soviet/Russian science. But nothing I could find on this.

Comment: @Timofey: for example among the things challenged by Western specialists are Slovo o polku Igoreve and Correpondence of Ivan IV with Kurbskii. But not a single word about those birch letters from a Western scientist!

Comment: There are not only state sanctioned "historical" truths but religions/cults sanctioned so-called historical truth and this mostly applies to so-called historical events and characters in Bible and Koran.

Answer (score 4):

I'm sure there are tons of examples (there are national myths in every culture and country and time), a couple of ones I can think of that are no longer supported but were important in ancient times are the [claimed descent from Antiquity of Medieval rulers](http://www.geni.com/projects/Descents-from-Antiquity/12283), the non-existent [Battle of Clavijo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Clavijo) in Early Medieval Spain, and the forged [Donation of Constantine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Donation_of_Constantine) that supported the Papacy's claim to temporal power.